# track adsense for eache page

Tags: javascript, php, statistics, adsense

Is there a way to track adsense income for each page.
I have a website where more users (1000+) manage there own page and I like to give them there share.
Can't find on adsense pay per page stats or export something usefull for this.
Somebody any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. create custom channels in AdSense (up to 500, if it is not enough, go to *2*)
2. connect your Google Analytics with your AdSense account.
   Go to *Analytics* > *Behavior* > *AdSense* > *AdSense Pages* and you will see all statistics for every url.